Blender crashes after variable amount of frames, or after scene edit
I have a problem with animation render. The render starts, but after a variable number of frames (usually around 500), blender crashes.
My scene is pretty big, over 20M tris, filled with vegetation.
I have already tried every "classic" performance optimization trick, i.e. persistent data, lock interface, and so on. The weird thing is that if I lauch blender and start a render it always works. But if I edit something in the scene and start a new render, it sometimes gets stuck during initialization, but if I close and open blender again and hit render it works. So it maybe have something to do with caching, I don't know.
The plugins I'm using that may be causing the issue are

Geo-Scatter
Grassblade
Bproduction Forestation

Specs: 

Blender 4.1
GPU RTX 4090
i7 12th gen

Logfile: 
https://pastebin.com/5ypyLDep
Thank you all

Sorry but we can't help with crashes on this Q&A site, especially if they might involve third-party addons. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Hi,  user186061. I hate to sound unhelpful, but I have to agree with John Eason, here. There's not much we can do as a community, here.. the inconsistency of the behaviour does suggest this is not a problem that can be solved by altering your  usage of the application.. so we can't help. Please go ahead and make a bug report, to draw this to the attention of the people who can help: the developers.
